# HTML code gets inserted as text with dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react JS

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using a library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draft-wysiwyg as rich text editor I am storing the edited content in MongoDB.

React Editor state value which is being passed through an API to mongo

```
draftToHtml(convertToRaw(newState.getCurrentContent()))
```

MongoDB Object:

```
&lt;p>React &lt;ins>Rich text editor&lt;/ins> library.&lt;/p>
&lt;ul>
&lt;li>Easy to use &lt;/li>
&lt;li>Customizable &lt;/li>
&lt;/ul>
&lt;p>&lt;/p>
```

While I try to set this as html in react component using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, the HTML code gets rendered as text in the div.

Here is the code snippet where I am using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML"

```
            <div
              style={{ color: 'white' }}
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(bookMarkNotes)}
            />
```

```
  function createMarkup(html) {
    console.log(html);
    return {
      __html: html
    };
  }

Here is the screenshot

[![Screenshot][1]][1]
```

Comment: It's being rendered as text because it's encoded in Mongo. You need to store the unencoded tags and return that to the frontend.

Comment: Thnks @KeithRousseau, could you help me understand how to do it.

Comment: I would check the output of draftToHtml and convertToRaw. Are either of those unencoded html?